# How to plot a curve in complex plane that include e constant

Tags: complex-numbers

I can understand how a complex numbers such as $10 + 7i$ can be plotted in complex plane with Imaginary and Real axis. But I have no idea how to approach this problem. I have been asked to plot $e^{(0.12+i) \theta\ } $.

I cannot understand what is the role of $ \theta\ $ in this equation. I also do not know how I can raise the power of Euler constant to a complex number. I appreciate any hint, comment, clue, reference, etc to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**  $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$

Parametric form of circle $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$

Comment: @Baqer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

Split it: $e^{(a+i)\theta}=e^{a\theta}e^{i\theta}$. Use the Awesome Hint to see that the product contains an exponentially growing and a oscillating part...

Comment: The Awesome Hint... I see what you did there... :P

Comment: "Awesome hint" +1